# Problem using telerik to apply skin to datagrid

Tags: view, grid, telerik, skin

I tempted to apply skin to my winform application which has many datagrids.
Many people recommend telerik and I changed datagrids to telerik's gridview.
Unfortunately gridview's properties and events name alot differently in telerik and standard winforms datagrid. and I have to rewrite a lot of code from scratch
Is there simpler alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want to use Telerik's grid, you have to go through the hard process of rewriting the code to work with the new events, etc. unfortunately.

We've all  been there :-)

HTH.